# TEB-NAS Midsize Jet max weight

Tags: jet, weight-and-balance, weight, private-jets, cessna-citation

We have hours with Sentient Jet and typically fly their Midsize jets -- Hawker 800, Citation XLS, Lear 60 etc. Usually only the XLS will work for us due to large luggage.

Can someone help with me with maximum weight for our trip combined with our routing?
I am not sure we will fit or be able to do non-stop due to pass/weight.
Last time we flew 6 pass + little less luggage and had to make a stop half way in South Carolina. I am thinking at least we will need to do this again.

As an alternative - I might call Sentient and ask if they can source us a Citation Latitude or Legacy 450 which I think will work? But they may consider these Super-Mids?
Otherwise we can upgrade to the Super Mid size category which of course is quite a price jump.

See info below and let me know any thoughts. Thank you....

- Route: TEB to NAS (Teterboro into Nassau Bahamas -- Just about 1,000 nautical miles?)
- Passengers: 7 adults + 1 child (about 1,300 lbs) + 2 pilots (400lbs)
- Luggage: 8 mid/large bags + 3 golf bags (about 550 lbs)
- Total weight excluding fuel = 2,250 lbs